# after upgrade python version 3.9 my virtualenv Import "django_filters.rest_framework" could not be resolved

Tags: python, django, django-filter

After upgrading python version 3.8 to 3.9, I have an issue in my virtual environment  Import "django_filters.rest_framework" could not be resolved.

```
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend

class Reviewlist(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ReviewSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['review_user__username', 'active']
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        return Review.objects.filter(watchlist=pk)
```

Comment: Did you delete your old virtualenv and create a new one to install requirements after the upgrade to 3.9?

Comment: No, I did not make any changes to my current  virtualenv

Comment: What's your env configuration? Did you check your Python path after upgrading?

Comment: Yes, I checked it, my virtualenv has a different python path, so I did change it now it's working fine.